# Typescript for NodeJS and Browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser

I am new to nodejs (familiar with typescript and JS). I am having a problem using typescript to create code that will work for both the browser and nodejs using typescript. Given the below example code, I would like the class to be reusable on both node and in the browser.

-index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myabstractclass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myclass.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myclass = new sample.myclass();
        myclass.log("hello world");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

-nodeserver.ts

```
var express = require('express');
var webapp = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').Server(webapp);

var mac = require('./myabstractclass');
var mc = require('./myclass');
mc.log("hello world");

var port = 8081;

webapp.use('/js', express.static(__dirname));
webapp.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port);
});
```

-myclass.ts

```
namespace sample {
    export class myclass extends scripts.myabstractclass {

    }
}
```

-myabstractclass.ts

```
namespace scripts {
    export class myabstractclass {
        public log(val: string): void {
            console.log(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you provide same code as JS to give some idea? What is this 'dom' abstraction for? Why are you using jQuery in Node (obviously, you won't succeed)?

Comment: The dom object is for unit testing so in my unit test I can create a div to make sure the stuff I append is there. I don't really want to use jquery in node, but I want to reuse the class on both sides. The config would hold any info that various projects can extend. IE, my current project is setting up a boolean to use socket.io. if(config.usingsocket) setup client side includes, setup server side includes. I believe a simple example of getting the inheritance, requires, and namespaces in the above example will help push me in the right direction.

Comment: You can't reuse it on both sides because Node code shouldn't contain anything dom-related. It's unclear what this 'config' is for. Usually configuration is some structure that can be expressed as JSON. In your case it's just some container. If it's supposed to be used only once, you're also abusing `class`.The question is too broad for SO in its current state, asking for some random example is off-topic. It's unclear what this example is supposed to contain any way. You can start with *not* using namespaces until you will be sure you need them - you've got ES modules to structure your code.

Comment: I've updated the code with a more thorough example. Although, I think you took to much stock into my Config class name. My goals are clear, I wanted to be able to use typescript to create browser and nodejs code, which might include inheritance or requires. The JQuery thing was just an example in the code (again, I think you took to much stock in it), I know it is possible to include jquery in node, so I am not sure what the big deal was with my example. However, if I use require in my file it no longer works in the browser, if I use inheritance or namepsaces it does not work in node.

Comment: I'd like to give some advice but I'm not sure where to start. First of all, you need to have 2 different build configs for browser and Node - separate TS configs, etc. Node is only TS with ES6 `target` and commonjs `module`. Browser is Webpack+TS with ES5 target and preferably `es6` module. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html for reference. It's preferable to stick to ES6 modules (`import`) and get rid of namespaces because they aren't really needed there. I'd personally use `ts-node` to skip build process for Node.

Comment: You can check any framework-agnostic starter kit for some ideas regarding toolchain for browser build, e.g. https://github.com/nobrainr/typescript-webpack-starter . Hope this helps. Since entire source code cannot be shared between browser and Node, you'll  likely end up with `shared` folder or something for common code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @estus I did take your advice and abstracted out the document and jquery elements for a UI only class (in my main project).

I feel comfortable with the approach that I ended up taking (although it might be considered hackish). I basically use module.exports at the bottom of each file, and set everything into a global scope. Then I include the file once, and can set `declare var` anywhere i need the import, since I set everything to the global scope specific, everything exists after my first call. The nicest part, now my required file is reusable.

Here are my updated files, which works both on node and in the browser using typescript.

--index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myabstractclass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myclass.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myclass = new sample.myclass();
        myclass.log("hello world");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

--nodeserver.ts

```
require('./required');

declare var webapp;
declare var express;
declare var server;
declare var path;
declare var myclass;

var m = new sample.myclass();
m.log('hello world');


var port = 8081;

webapp.use('/js', express.static(__dirname));
webapp.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port);
});
```

--myclass.ts

```
namespace sample {
    export class myclass extends scripts.myabstractclass {

    }
}

if (typeof (module) != 'undefined') {
    module.exports = sample.myclass;
}
```

--myabstractclass.ts

```
namespace scripts {
    export class myabstractclass {
        public log(val: string): void {
            console.log(val);
        }
    }
}

if (typeof (module) != 'undefined') {
    module.exports = scripts.myabstractclass;
}
```

--required.ts

```
global.express = require('express');
global.webapp = express();
global.path = require('path');
global.server = require('http').Server(webapp);
global.scripts = {};
global.scripts.myabstractclass = require('./myabstractclass');
global.sample = {};
global.sample.myclass = require('./myclass');
```